# Parameter value is null in xsl template

Tags: xslt

I am calling a template as below:

```
<select class="inline" name="time-of-trip-begin-hour" id="time-of-trip-begin-hour">
                <xsl:call-template name="createDropDown">
                    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="23" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="selectedValue" select="$dropDownValue" />
                </xsl:call-template>
 </select>
```

Templete definition:

```
 <xsl:template name="createDropDown">
            <xsl:param name="index" select="0" />
            <xsl:param name="count" />
            <xsl:param name="selectedValue" />

            <xsl:if test="$index &lt;= 9">
                <option>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',$index)" />
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',$index)" />
                </option>
                <xsl:call-template name="createDropDown">
                    <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="($index &gt; 9) and ($index &lt;= $count)">
                <option>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$index" />
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:if test=" $selectedValue = $index ">
                        <xsl:attribute name="selected">
                            <xsl:value-of select=" 'true' " />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$index" />
                </option>
                <xsl:call-template name="createDropDown">
                    <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

However the value of `$selectedValue` is null everytime although there is value in `$dropDownValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the template recursively twice in your code, but in none of your recursive calls you are copying the value for the `$selectedValue` parameter.

Try adding it to your call-templates:

```
<xsl:call-template name="createDropDown">
    <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count" />
    <xsl:with-param name="selectedValue" select="$selectedValue" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: it is still not working. the value itself is not passing to the template actually..

Comment: Then add a `<xsl:message select="$selectedValue" />` before you call the template to be sure of the value of `selectedValue`. It might be null before you called in in the first place. Add some more context to your question (all the other templates involved, or even your full xsl)

Comment: (`<xsl:message select="$selectedValue" />` is for debugging - you can see in the console the values you decide to print)

Comment: yes it is working now.. i forgot to replace the snippet in two positions :)